# Notepad ++ Remove start and end of a string while keeping the middle

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a text file that contains something like this:

```
iosudhfsdkflasgj \aaa asdgsdga3453t.ggsdg\n \bbb
hjdfghjdfgjhh \ccc jtj56ywyrty546y \bbb 
yjksfgh \aaa sefgwetgwgeregerg \bbb
u56j56jh \ddd agfwegaewrg\n \bbb
```

Basically the string in the middle have letters, number and sometimes `\n` at the end, right before `\bbb`. The string in the middle can have few or many characters.

I want to remove the strings `\aaa` and `\bbb` where is starting with `\aaa` and ending with `\bbb`, but keep the middle part. I also don't want to touch those starting with `\ccc`, `\ddd`, `\eee` ...

The result should look like:

```
iosudhfsdkflasgj asdgsdga3453t.ggsdg\n
hjdfghjdfgjhh \ccc jtj56ywyrty546y \bbb 
yjksfgh sefgwetgwgeregerg 
u56j56jh \ddd agfwegaewrg\n \bbb
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1387557/edit) and add at least the desired result or real text and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\\aaa(\b.+?)\\bbb`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\\aaa       # \aaa (the backslash has to be escaped)
(\b.+?)     # group 1, a word boundry, 1 or more any character, not greedy
\\bbb       # \bbb (the backslash has to be escaped)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
iosudhfsdkflasgj  asdgsdga3453t.ggsdg\n 
hjdfghjdfgjhh \ccc jtj56ywyrty546y \bbb 
yjksfgh  sefgwetgwgeregerg 
u56j56jh \ddd agfwegaewrg\n \bbb
```